# Access pdf file from local directory and display pdf on new tab

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a directory which consists of PDF files. I want to open the PDF on a new tab on button click. I tried window.open("file:///...") but it gives Access from script is denied. How can I open the PDF?

Comment: You need to provide a path relative to the js/ts file where you calling `window.open`... So for example `window.open('../../assets/pdfFiles/someFile.pdf`)`

Comment: @callback When I do this, my angular page gets reloaded each time a pdf is uploaded and saved in the assets folder. How can I encounter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your file in asset folder, this is a example:

```
   this.openFile("help.pdf");

   openFile(fileName) {
        window.open("assets/documents/" + fileName);
    }
```